# How to cycle through items in Android RecyclerView?

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview

How can you cycle through the items in an Android RecyclerView?

I would like to have a RecyclerView that scrolls horizontally. When the end is reached to the right, it simply continues scrolling by restarting the list of items. the same to the left.

---

**For example:**
List of items: 0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9
Starting view shows: 0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7
After scrolling 5 items to the right: 5,6,7,8,9,0,1,2
After scrolling 2 items to the left: 8,9,0,1,2,3,4,5

Comment: extend the `RecyclerView` as usual, overriding necessary methods that retrieve next / previous element and update index to zero / max value when reaching limits.....

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Another idea would be, make `getItemCount()` of your adapter return `Integer.MAX_VALUE` and then in order to get your item, you would call `itemsList.get(position % list.size)`. 
This way, when the scrolling goes beyond your actual list size, it restarts from 0 and shows the first element of the list after the last one.
One more thing to do could be calling `scrollToPosition(int x)` on the `LayoutManager` where `x % yourList.size() == 0` and x being somwhere close to `Integer.MAX_VALUE / 2`, this way the scroll would look like infinite (~1 billion positions in every direction from the starting point).

As pointed out in comment, if the list size is 0 `getItemCount` should return 0. E.g.

```
return list.size == 0 ? 0 : Integer.MAX_VALUE
```

Comment: I think it will work perfect if we just scroll it to the right, but when we scroll it to the left, how to calculate?

Comment: the way i described it will start from 0 index, so you wouldn't be able to scroll to the left of that, one thing you could do is calling `scrollToPosition(int x)` on the `LayoutManager` where `x % yourList.size() == 0` and x being somewhere close to `Integer.MAX_VALUE / 2` in this way the scroll would look like infinite (~1 billion positions in every direction from the starting point)

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for and it works perfectly. Thanks!

Comment: i do exact like this but at this line "itemsList.get(position % list.size)" i got divide by zero error . when change getItemCount to return Integer.MAX_VALUE; seems list.size() always return 0

Comment: you should modify `getItemCount` so that if the list is empty it returns 0

Comment: i modify getItemCount to list.size()*10000 . and work , cause when use Integer.MAX_VALUE list.size return 0 . but any way u got + vote ;)

Comment: doing that way your risk of having integer overflow, I would suggest to do it this way `return list.size == 0 ? 0 : Integer.MAX_VALUE`

Answer (score -3):

I have an idea like this
First make new list = 3x original list

```
original list: 0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9
new list     : 0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9
```

When first time display the `RecyclerView`, your should scroll the `RecyclerView` to the right 10 items (10 is the size of original list). Then if user scroll to left or right less than 10 items it will work like a circle.

**And** when they reach the end of the right or left, you should scroll `RecyclerView` back to the state that you first time display the `RecyclerView`.
Correct me if I'm wrong. Thanks for helping

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion, but I'm going with the one @lelloman suggested. It doesn't require so much data to be stored.